# Java unmarshaller not parsing simple type being a decimal, with regex rules defined

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, bigdecimal

I'm having problem with java unmarshaller. Whole code was built based on an xsd fedinition. There I have decimal type defined as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="KMTyp">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="3"/>
        <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{3}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

for defined attribute:

```
<xs:attribute name="KM_OD" type="KMTyp"/>
```

However unmarshaller does not read this attribute correctly from xml file:

```
<ODCINEK KM_OD="21.000" KM_DO="21.050">
```

It always returns null. Code responsible for processing xml looks as follows:

```
AONA50 item = new AONA50();

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(item.getClass());
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

unmarshaller.setSchema(schema50);
Object xmlObject = item.getClass().cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(fileName)));

return (AONA50)xmlObject;
```

Could anyone help me please, to make this work, so correct BigDecimal values are red from xml and returned?

//edit here is AONA50 class: http://pastebin.com/WM6XfvyW

Comment: Could you add more details? ... e.g `AONA50` class

Comment: sure. it's here as it's too big to be pasted http://pastebin.com/WM6XfvyW

Comment: If use `<ODCINEK KM_OD="21.000" KM_DO="21.050">` don't works for me... works fine if i use `<AONA KM_OD="21.000" KM_DO="21.050"/>`

Comment: this won't help :( sample data looks like this:

  <ODCINEK KM_OD="21.000" KM_DO="21.050">
   <WGS_POCZ LAT="51.6208898488" LON="14.7965188317" ALT="174.23"></WGS_POCZ>
   <WGS_KON LAT="51.6212342188" LON="14.7969821217" ALT="172.23"></WGS_KON>
   <PS_M>12.3</PS_M>
   <PS_D>4.3</PS_D>
   <PPD_M>11.3</PPD_M>
   <PPD_D>6.3</PPD_D>
   <PPP_M>11.3</PPP_M>
   <PPP_D>6.3</PPP_D>
   <LA_M>0</LA_M>
   <LA_D>4.3</LA_D>
   <UB>1.4</UB>
   <WY>2.3</WY>
   <DROP>35.1</DROP>
   <CURB>35.1</CURB>
   <P_PS>34.42</P_PS>
   <P_PP>12.11</P_PP>
  </ODCINEK>

Comment: try to carry out a marshal using `AONA50` so we can see correct xml.

Comment: Ok.. seems that you need `@XmlElement` not an `@XmlAttribute`. remap your java attributes.

Comment: ok, my mistake. found a solution. I was trying to get KM_OD and KM_DO from main aona50 object instead of list of ODCINKI. sorry, my bad :)

Comment: I recommend you to add your answer below. :)